# change browser's Internet settings using java code

Tags: java, proxy, browser

I am trying to spawn a browser using a small java code

```
String command="rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler http://www.google.com"
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

The above thing works fine. However there certain difficulties I am facing.

1. I need to change the proxy settings of the browser.
2. Since the above code spawns the default web browser, first of all I am not able to find the default browser. Secondly, how do I change the proxy settings for that particular browser?

I tried to implement following code, but its not working:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

But what I can understand is that its for JVM and not for the browser. And I need to change this for a particular browser.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2):

My answer may not fully help you but it can guide you a bit.

There is totally not related to System.setProperty. This method sets VM system property.

What you are trying to do is 'change Windows property'. Then you should find solution by Windows command (not by java) as you already did:

```
String command="xxxx"
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would say that rather than "change Windows Property", I need to "change browser property". But I need some pointers and a direction to proceed. And I have to do this using java. Any help will be helpful.

Comment: You should ask with "Windows" tag instead of java because what you really need is 'xxxx', not anything about Java.